# How to check in an object whether its has the key or not?

Tags: javascript

```
var object = [{key1:'value',key2:'value2'},{'key1:'value',key2:'value2}]

for (var key in object)
     {
      if(!object.hasOwnProperty(key)){continue;}
```

Why do we get error? Am i checking the right way.

I get an `error cannot call hasOwnProperty in an Object - TypeError`

Comment: Please post a complete example with *valid* syntax. This is obviously not a full example of your actual code. It is impossible to tell anything from what you've posted.

Comment: Quotes seem to be messed up and the array is called `array` and not `object`

Comment: @andyb: just messed up things

Comment: @John: So now you're doing a `for-in` over an Array? Is this your actual code? Looking at your previous question you had `array` and `arrayObj` for names, so it seems that you're excluding some code. Now you've changed `array` to `object`, which changes the meaning. Please post actual code that represents your actual issue.

Comment: ...and your syntax is still **invalid** so this would never run. Please post an actual working example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`object` is not defined. Check this revision:

```
var myarr = [{key1:'value',key2:'value2'},{key1:'value',key2:'value2'}];
//renamed to myarr to avoid confusion - and removed typos from your code. 
//myarr is now an array of objects

//loop through myarr
for (var i=0;i<myarr.length;i=i+1){

 //check if the element myarr[i] is indeed an object
 if (myarr[i].constructor === Object) {

   //loop through the object myarr[i]
   for (var key in myarr[i])  {

      //notice the removal of !
      if(myarr[i].hasOwnProperty(key)){
         /* do things */
      }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: @Kooilnc: What does the removal of !{NOT} signify here... Is it wrong to be placed

Comment: @John: you don't need it. Roughly translating you question, you want to check if property belongs to the object you are looping. You use the `hasOwnProperty` of the object you're looping, so if that returns true you know the property belongs to the object (and not to one of the object 'ancestors' if applicable). Otherwise the loop `continue`s to the next key without the need to explicitly initiate that.

Answer (score 0):

Is your for-loop correct? Try this

```
for (var key in array)
{
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined `object` in your for loop.  Your array of objects above is named `array`.

```
for (var key in array) {

}
```